# how to query some values that different based on another value

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I would like to know how can I make query to return values that have another different "*value*" based on, hmm i don't know what it should be called, *identifier*? For example, I have data like :

```
id    | date       | user | item  |      material      | Text | Description |
------+------------+------+-------+--------------------+------+-------------+
12345 | 31.03.2015 | ID00 | 00010 | 000000001011000106 | abcd |  something  | 
12345 | 31.03.2015 | ID00 | 00020 | 000000001011010105 | abcd |  test       |
12345 | 31.03.2015 | ID00 | 00030 | 000000001011020106 | abcd |  something  |
12345 | 31.03.2015 | ID00 | 00040 | 000000001011020104 | abcd |  something  |
44455 | 31.03.2015 | ID00 | 00010 | 000000001011040106 | abcd |  something  |
44455 | 31.03.2015 | ID00 | 00020 | 000000001011000105 | abcd |  something  |
44455 | 31.03.2015 | ID00 | 00030 | 000000001011010104 | abcd |  something  |
67890 | 31.03.2015 | ID00 | 00010 | 000000001011100402 | abcd |  something  |
77777 | 31.03.2015 | ID00 | 00010 | 000000001011100402 | bcad |  something  |
80808 | 31.03.2015 | ID00 | 00010 | 000000001011140102 | abcd |  something  |
90009 | 31.03.2015 | ID00 | 00010 | 000000001011100102 | dcba |  something  |
66666 | 01.04.2015 | ID00 | 00010 | 000000001011160101 | cdab |  somesome   |
```

And, I want to get result **based on *id* and *description* only**.
Let say, all id *'44455'* have value for description which is *'something'*. **It shouldn't be displayed**. But for id *'12345'* all the description is *'something'* except 1 row that contain different value which is, *'test'*

So, the rows that should be displayed are **description** that contains value *null*, and rows that contains different values **description** based on identifier **id**. From the example above, it should be printed:

```
id    | date       | user | item  |      material      | Text | Description |
------+------------+------+-------+--------------------+------+-------------+
12345 | 31.03.2015 | ID00 | 00010 | 000000001011000106 | abcd |  something  | 
12345 | 31.03.2015 | ID00 | 00020 | 000000001011010105 | abcd |  test       |
12345 | 31.03.2015 | ID00 | 00030 | 000000001011020106 | abcd |  something  |
12345 | 31.03.2015 | ID00 | 00040 | 000000001011020104 | abcd |  something  |
```

How can I make a condition in query for this case? Any advise?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query using `EXISTS`.

Assuming your table name is tbl, then the query is:

```
select *
from tbl a
where exists (select 1 from tbl b where a.id = b.id and b.description <> 'Something');
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this query

```
select *
from tbl a
where 1 < (select count(*) from tbl b where a.id = b.id group by b.description);
```